# Align center inside relative container position

Tags: css

Actually i have this css for show 2 cols and inside of cols button to the end of each col , this button must show always to the end of col and in the center of col , but no get this code works , also when i put the width of the button to 5o% of container in col , this show bad , and if use pixels show ok , in all cases never in the center , i put my code here :

```
#container
{
position:relative;
width:90%;  
margin:auto;
border:1px solid #111;
overflow:hidden;
text-align:center;  
}

#col
{
display:inline-block;
width:20%;
min-height:300px;
text-align:left;
background-color:red;
margin-bottom:-9000px;
padding-bottom:9000px;
vertical-align:top; 
}

.access
{
position: absolute;
width:50%;
height:35px;
background-color:#111111;
color:#ffffff;
border:0px solid;
bottom:3px; 
}

<div id="container">
<div id="col">
Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are Youi77 ? Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br><br>
<div style="height:40px;"></div>
<input type="submit" name="Access" value="Access Now" class="access" />
</div>
<div id="col">
Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>Hi , How Are You ?<br>
<div style="height:40px;"></div>
<input type="submit" name="Access" value="Access Now" class="access" />
</div>
</div>
```

You can see the test here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ljzemk11/

Comment: You can't re-use IDs on a page. Try using a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to place the button at the bottom of each column.

In that case, the `position:relative` needs to be on the `.col` CLASS (becuase *you can't re-use IDs on a page*.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #111;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  min-height: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
.access {
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 10%;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #111111;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px solid;
  bottom: 3px;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="col">Hi , How Are You ?


    <div style="height:40px;"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="Access" value="Access Now" class="access" />
  </div>
  <div class="col">Hi , How Are You ?
    <br>Hi , How Are You ?
    <br>Hi , How Are You ?
    <br>
    <div style="height:40px;"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="Access" value="Access Now" class="access" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This no well because i need the cols grow the same time for this i put margin-bottom:-9000px;
padding-bottom:9000px;

Comment: You can still use that if you want. I just took it out for space.